# How to maintain "-6" as UTC offset during CDT?

Tags: java, date, timezone, xmlgregoriancalendar

I want to retain CST time always with offset -6, at present I am getting as `2018-03-15T05:08:53-05:00`.

But I want to change it as with offset -6 like `2018-03-15T05:08:53-06:00` through out the year.

```
TimeZone tz= TimeZone.getdefault();

if(tz.inDayLightTime())
{
    getCSTDate(cal)
    // I would like to change the logic here. 
}

public XMLGregorianCalendar getCSTDate(Calendar cal)
{
    return XMLGregorianCalendar; 
}
```

my input type : calendar
output : XMLGregorianCalendar

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to keep -6 the entire year?  Do you have a scenario or a physical place that does this?  If so, please elaborate - there is likely a better solution.

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: The `TimeZone` and `Calendar` classes are long outdated. Likely there is also a better solution than using `XMLGregorianCalendar`, so you may also want to elaborate on why you want one.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode, with its team advising migration to the *java.time* classes.

Comment: Your comments are entirely different than your question here. Please take more care to think through your issues before posting. And search before posting – all these issues have been covered on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Then don't use a timezone that tracks Daylight Saving Time changes (which is probably the case of yours `TimeZone.getDefault()`).

If you want a fixed offset, you can do:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-06:00");
```

Not sure why you want that, because if you're dealing with timezones, you must consider DST effects. And `2018-03-15T05:08:53-06:00` is not the same instant as `2018-03-15T05:08:53-05:00`, so changing the offset while keeping all the other fields is usually wrong - as it's not clear why you want that and what you want to achieve, I can't give you more advice on that.

Comment: am checking the day belongs to same day or previous day, am expecting the day should be same day. for some reason on 11/march mid night.. the date 2018-03-11T04:08:53-05:00 , early morning 4am.. but when i compare calendar date with  2018-03-11T04:08:53-05:00 , it gave me miss match.

Comment: @jcrshankar Perhaps you should edit your question then, to explain all of this and people can come up with a proper answer. Because checking if the day is the same has nothing to do with CSTxCDT offsets (at least based on the information on the question)

Comment: FYI, [`TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, and should be avoided. Supplanted by the *java.time* classes, specifically [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) and [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

If you want the current moment as seen through a fixed [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) with [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
OffsetDateTime.now( 
    ZoneOffset.ofHours( -6 )
)
```

## Details

> always with offset -6

The [Answer by watssu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49322992/642706) is correct: If you don’t want the effects of Daylight Saving Time (DST), don’t use a time zone that respects DST.

If you always want an offset-from-UTC fixed at six hours behind UTC, use an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( -6 ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( offset ) ;  // Ignores DST, offset is fixed and unchanging.
```

Be clear that an offset is simply a number hours, minutes, and seconds displacement from UTC. In contrast, a time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes in offset used by the people of a particular region. So generally, you should be using a time zone rather than a mere offset. Your insistence on a fixed offset is likely unwise.

The 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `CST` are *not* time zones. They are used by mainstream media to give a rough idea about time zone and indicate if DST is in effect. But they are *not*standardized. [They are not even unique](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)! For example, CST means *Central Standard Time* as well as *China Standard Time* or *Cuba Standard Time*.

Use real time zones with names in the format of `continent/region`.

Avoid all the legacy date-time classes such as `TimeZone` now supplanted by the *java.time* classes. Specifically, `ZoneId`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Respects DST changes in offset.
```

If your real issue is wanting to detect DST to alter your logic, I suggest you rethink the problem. I suspect you are attacking the wrong issue. But if you insist, you can ask for the offset currently in effect on your `ZonedDateTime`, and you can ask a `ZoneId` if DST is in effect for any particular moment via the `ZoneRules` class.

```
ZoneOffset offsetInEffect = zdt.getOffset() ;
```

And…

```
Boolean isDstInEffect = zdt.getZone.getRules().isDaylightSavings( zdt.toInstant() ) ;
```

On that last line, note the incorrect use of plural with `s` on `isDaylightSavings`.

The [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) class is part of the troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the *java.time* classes, specifically `ZonedDateTime`. To inter-operate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert to the modern class via the legacy class `GregorianCalendar`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myXmlCal.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).